# How to retrieve today and tomorrow's values in a specific tab of a dynamic calendar

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-calendar, google-sheets-dates

Employees are selected in their corresponding shift on each month tab in a dynamic calendar
See 092022 tab in my example:

[image: See 092022 tab in my example]

I want Pemanence tab will be able to retrieve automatically the values in the good current month tab based on TODAY's and TOMORROW's dates as I filled manually the values here :
[image]

I share with you my work as I need your help
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zMgnIVAy71M_LX7VMs2IqnBgxO4eVZhatNkfjh0OSEw/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 0):

With a similar approach than the other question, if you keep the exact same format than in sheet 092022 you can use this formula:

> =INDIRECT(TEXT(Month(C7),"00")&year(C7)&"!R"&6+13*ROUNDUP((Day(C7)-weekday(C7,2))/7,0)&"C"&2*WEEKDAY(C7,2)-1&":R"&17+13*ROUNDUP((DAY(C7)-weekday(C7,2))/7,0)&"C"&2*WEEKDAY(C7,2),
> FALSE)

See it working in this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zMgnIVAy71M_LX7VMs2IqnBgxO4eVZhatNkfjh0OSEw/edit?usp=drivesdk